# SharePoint online management shell script to checked in all files

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I have SPO site and trying to check in checked out files (also inside folders) under "Shared Document" library. This PS script should checked in all files under single document library. I have tried below power shell code but it throws error.

```
    Connect-SPOService –Url https://***-admin.sharepoint.com –Credential jinesh@coctees.onmicrosoft.com
Add-Type -Path "E:/sp/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"   
Add-Type -Path "E:/sp/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"   




$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/tesst"
$listName = "Shared Documents"
$list = $spWeb.Lists |? {$_.Title -eq $listName}
foreach ($item in $list.Items) 
{
    $itemFile = $item.File
    if( $itemFile.CheckOutStatus -ne "None" )
    { 
        $itemFile.CheckIn("Automatic CheckIn. (Administrator)")
    }
}
$spWeb.Dispose()
```

Error:

```
Get-SPWeb : The term 'Get-SPWeb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:10
 $spWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://coctees.sharepoint.com/sites/tesst"
         ~~~~~~~~~
     CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-SPWeb:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Thanks.

Comment: could you please add the detail about error, it will help to understand the issue

Answer (score 1):

I did some job using PowerShell + REST API. My Script bellow is to create a site inside a site collection. I have taken it from a website. This has shown me how to deal with SPO using powershell and REST API

## Configuration

$TenantUrl = "https://yoursitel.sharepoint.com"
$Username = "sharepoint@yoursite"
$Password = 'password'

$SiteTitle =  $args[0]
$SiteUrl = "https://yoursitel.sharepoint.com""+ $args[1] # Note this URL must be available (check with "/_api/GroupSiteManager/GetValidSiteUrlFromAlias")
$SiteTemplate = "" # "Topic" => leave empty (default), "Showcase" => "6142d2a0-63a5-4ba0-aede-d9fefca2c767" and "Blank" => "f6cc5403-0d63-442e-96c0-285923709ffc"

## Communication site creation request

$RequestBody = '{"request":{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Publishing.PublishingSiteCreationRequest"},"Title":"' + $SiteTitle + '","Url":"' + $SiteUrl + '","Description":"","Classification":"","SiteDesignId":"' + $SiteTemplate + '","AllowFileSharingForGuestUsers":false}}'

if ($SiteTemplate -eq "")
{
    $RequestBody = '{"request":{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Publishing.PublishingSiteCreationRequest"},"Title":"' + $SiteTitle + '","Url":"' + $SiteUrl + '","Description":"","Classification":"","AllowFileSharingForGuestUsers":false}}'
}

## Get a user based context for SharePoint (app credentials not supported for this approach)

$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($TenantUrl)
$Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $(ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force))
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

## Get url, cookie and forms digest for authentication

$RequestUrl = "$($TenantUrl)/_api/sitepages/publishingsite/create"
$AuthenticationCookie = $Context.Credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie($TenantUrl, $true)
$FormsDigest = $Context.GetFormDigestDirect()

$WebSession = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$WebSession.Credentials = $Context.Credentials
$WebSession.Cookies.SetCookies($TenantUrl, $AuthenticationCookie)

$Headers = @{ 
    'X-RequestDigest' = $FormsDigest.DigestValue;
    'accept' = 'application/json;odata=verbose';
    'content-type' = 'application/json;odata=verbose' }

## Call REST API to create new site

$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -WebSession $WebSession -Headers $Headers -ContentType "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8" -Body $RequestBody -Uri $RequestUrl -UseDefaultCredentials

$Context.Dispose()

## Site has been created

Write-Output "New site created at: $($Result.d.Create.SiteUrl)"

Comment: I take this script from a site I can´t remember I´m trying to find it now

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because “Get-SPWeb” is for SharePoint On-premise environment.

In SharePoint Online, you can use the script below to find all checked out file and check in them:

```
function Get-SPOFolderFiles
{
param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [string]$Username,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
        [string]$Url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)]
        $password,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=4)]
        [string]$ListTitle
        )


  $ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
  $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $password)
  $ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  $ll=$ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
  $ctx.Load($ll)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  $spqQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
 $spqQuery.ViewXml ="<View Scope='RecursiveAll' />";
   $itemki=$ll.GetItems($spqQuery)
   $ctx.Load($itemki)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

  foreach($item in $itemki)
  {

  Write-Host $item["FileRef"] $item.ElementType

  $file =
        $ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($item["FileRef"]);
        $ctx.Load($file)
        $ctx.Load($file.Versions)     

         $ctx.Load($file.ListItemAllFields)
        $Author=$file.Author
        $CheckedOutByUser=$file.CheckedOutByUser
        $LockedByUser=$file.LockedByUser
        $ModifiedBy=$file.ModifiedBy
        $ctx.Load($Author)
        $ctx.Load($CheckedOutByUser)
        $ctx.Load($LockedByUser)
        $ctx.Load($ModifiedBy)
        $ctx.Load($file.EffectiveInformationRightsManagementSettings)
        $ctx.Load($file.Properties)
        $ctx.Load($file.VersionEvents)
        try
        {
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        }
        catch
        {}

       if($CheckedOutByUser.LoginName -ne $null){
       Write-Host $file.Name
       Write-Host $CheckedOutByUser.LoginName
       $file.CheckIn('Checked in automatically', 'MajorCheckIn')
  $ctx.Load($file)
  try
  {
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()        
  Write-Host $file.Name " has been checked in"     -ForegroundColor DarkGreen 
  }
        catch [Net.WebException]
     { 
        Write-Host $_.Exception.ToString()
     }

       }



     }   
  }

#Paths to SDK
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

#Enter the data
$AdminPassword=Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$username="user@testlz.onmicrosoft.com"
$Url="https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/"
$ListTitle="libraryname"

Get-sPOFolderFiles -Username $username -Url $Url -password $AdminPassword -ListTitle $ListTitle
```

More information and PowerShell script file download in the article below:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Find-all-checked-out-files-56fd562d#content